# Dynamically build a LINQ statement

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to build a LINQ query dynamically. In this example I have one of two locations for the value of one of the fields I thought I could do something like this....

```
Dim newCompany = New IOCompany With {.Company = PCase(cmbx_Company.SelectedValue.Trim), _
                                     If cmb_CompanySchedule.SelectedIndex = 0 Then _
                                         .CompanySchedule = "StdSchedule", _
                                     Else
                                         .CompanySchedule = cmb_CompanySchedule.SelectedIndex, _
                                     End If _
                                    }

db.IOCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(newCompany)
db.SubmitChanges()
Result = newCompany.CID
```

But of course this is wrong... How can I do something like this... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with LINQ.

Just don't use `With` for `CompanySchedule`:

```
Dim newCompany = New IOCompany With {.Company = PCase(cmbx_Company.SelectedValue.Trim) }
If cmb_CompanySchedule.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    newCompany.CompanySchedule = "StdSchedule"
Else
    newCompany.CompanySchedule = cmb_CompanySchedule.SelectedIndex
End If


db.IOCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(newCompany)
db.SubmitChanges()
Result = newCompany.CID
```

Comment: Daniel Thank a bundle... I had an idea I was so close but not close enough... now I have to wait 7 mins to accept your answer :)